# Why does a comma appear in the output after the string is used in unpacking in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

```
def func(*n):
    print(n)

func(1,2,3,4)
func(*(1,2,3))
func((1,2,3,'hey'))
func(('hey',1))
```

```
output:
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3)
((1, 2, 3, 'hey'),)
(('hey', 1),)
```

comma appears after tuple when string is added to the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is expected: the tuples you're passing into the function in the bottom two examples represent the first argument in the variadic `*args` tuple (the name doesn't matter, you used `*n`). The purpose of `*args` is to create a tuple containing all of the non-keyword arguments passed to a function.

Creating a single-element tuple always prints with a trailing comma to distinguish it as a tuple. In the bottom two cases, you have a single-element `args` tuple with a 4 or 2 element tuple as its lone element.

Your sentence "comma appears after tuple when string is added to the argument" is incorrect--you removed the unpacking operator `*` from the call which no longer flattens the tuple into variable arguments, so the string has nothing to do with it. You'd still get the hanging comma even if you passed a number as the lone argument:

```
>>> def f(*args): print(args)
...
>>> f(1)
(1,)          # `args` tuple contains one number
>>> f(1, 2)
(1, 2)        # `args` tuple contains two numbers
>>> f((1, 2))
((1, 2),)     # two-element tuple `(1, 2)` inside single-element `args` tuple
>>> f((1,))
((1,),)       # single-element tuple `(1,)` inside single-element `args` tuple
>>> f(*(1,))  # unpack the tuple in the caller, same as `f(1)`
(1,) 
>>> f(*(1,2)) # as above but with 2 elements
(1, 2) 
>>> f((1))    # without the trailing comma, `(1)` resolves to `1` and is not a tuple
(1,)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see a `,` after is because `()` is a function call where `(some_object,)` is a tuple.

```
>>> tuple()
()
>>> tuple([None])
(None,)
```

When you passed the args for the last two function calls notice the double `(())`

```
func((1,2,3,'hey'))
func(('hey',1))
```

So what you passed is a tuple for the last two.  See the types of each

```
>>> type(('test'))
<class 'str'>
>>> type(('test', 1))
<class 'tuple'>
```

If you don't want the trailing comma then remove the extra `()` around the args